# Instant or implicit type conversion for captured groups in MatchData

Tags: regex, ruby

I know that matching strings with Ruby's `Regexp` is inherently uh... string-based. But I've been amazed by novel Ruby solutions before, and I'm wondering whether a nice solution exists for this case:

Knowing that a matching group would allow a captured part to be converted to an `Integer` always... is there a way to express the `Regexp` or the `String#match` in such a way that the captured group in `MatchData` is converted to an integer instantly?

Sample:

```rb
line = "answer 42"
p line.match(/(\w+) (\d+)/).captures
```

returns
`["answer", "42"]`

I'm aiming to get a converted numeric type in the second group, as in
`["answer", 42]`

Using named groups in the `Regexp` doesn't matter:

```rb
line.match(/(?<string>\w+) (?<integer>\d+)/)
# => #<MatchData "answer 42" string:"answer" integer:"42">
```

If this isn't possible —and I doubt it is— what would be an elegant solution to convert some groups? Currently, for an array of such lines, I'm using this

```rb
lines.map { |line| line.match(/(\w+) (\d+)/).captures }
     .map { |string, integer| [string, integer.to_i] }
```

which does the job because of the explicit conversion by `String#to_i`.

Comment: Regular expressions are concerned exclusively with strings. As to ways of converting string representations of integers to integers, that is string-specific, so there is no general approach to that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer to the question (no explicit MatchData involved) but it may be useful and it's too long for a comment, so:

```
require 'csv'

line = "answer 42"
p CSV.parse_line(line, col_sep: " ", converters: :integer) # => ["answer", 42]
```

Comment: Creative although technically not too long for a comment (even with the "too long for a comment" part) :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought of applying the conversion of the parser in the `CSV` lib too - that's a solution too. Thanks for adding that as an answer (instead of as comment).